# Placing a bootstrap badge over the lower right corner of a <li> element of an <ul> list of unknown elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My conundrum is this: I'm trying to do absolute positioning relative to the regular flow of the list since I don't know how many there will be at any given time but my badge is taking the absolute position of the `<ul>` element instead.

My code:

```css
.buttons {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 148px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.buttons li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.count {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 18px;
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="buttons">
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span><span class="badge count">3</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ag1vgnqt/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `position: relative` to your list items:

```
.buttons li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.count {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ag1vgnqt/6/)

Comment: This works but I then have to hardcode the font size to get the lower right corner. Any idea on how to anchor it to start from that corner instead?

Comment: I think I got it. Right:0px; starts from the right, right? Thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for your needs:

```
.count {
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    right:18px;
    margin-right:-25px;
    background-color:#d9534f;
}
```

Just changed position to `relative`, added a negative `margin-right` and slightly adjusted the other variables. The `.badge` not floats at the bottom right of the `.list` icon.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ag1vgnqt/4/)